# Prometheus metrics where change interval and scrape interval are quite different

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I am struggling with PromQL over an issue dealing with a metric that
changes less frequently than the scrape interval. I am trying to use
Prometheus as a pseudo event tracker and hoping to get some advice on
how to best try and accomplish my goal.

I have a random job that runs at different intervals depending on the
situation. Some instances of the job run every five minutes and some run
only once an hour or once a day. The job created a node_exporter
textfile snippet that gets scraped on 30 second interval.

Below is an example of a metric that changes only every five minutes with
the lesser scrape interval. In this scenario all the points with same
value are from the same job run. I really only care about one of those.

I have no way to know what the interval is between set for all my
different jobs. All I know is that when the value changes, a new set is
in play.

What I want to do in "reduce" my dataset to deal with only distinct
values. I want to collapse these 27 entries into 3 by taking either the
first or last value of each "set".

I can not find a PromQL function/operator that does what I want. Maybe I
need to use recording rules?

All and any help is greatly appreciated.

metric_name{instance="hostname.example.net", job="external/generic", mode="pull", name="snafu"}

9973997301 @1673997343.774
9973997301 @1673997373.764
9973997301 @1673997403.764
9973997301 @1673997433.764
9973997301 @1673997463.764
9973997301 @1673997493.764
9973997301 @1673997523.764
9973997301 @1673997553.764
9973997301 @1673997583.764

9973997601 @1673997613.764
9973997601 @1673997643.764
9973997601 @1673997673.764
9973997601 @1673997703.774
9973997601 @1673997733.764
9973997601 @1673997763.764
9973997601 @1673997793.764
9973997601 @1673997823.764
9973997601 @1673997853.863

9973997901 @1673997913.764
9973997901 @1673997943.767
9973997901 @1673997973.764
9973997901 @1673998003.764
9973997901 @1673998033.764
9973997901 @1673998063.764
9973997901 @1673998093.764
9973997901 @1673998123.764
9973997901 @1673998153.764

I have tried many of the PromQL functions/operators to try and reduce my sets. The count_vaules() operator is the closest I have come but that works only with instant vectors not range vectors.